# Is $\operatorname{Gr}(\log(x)) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ a closed subset.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

We know that graph of a continuous function (target space being $T_2$) is a closed set. But the usual logarithm function , $\log:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous but cannot be extended continuously to $\mathbb{R}$. I am asking whether its graph is closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I have an intuitive idea that we could find open ball around each point in the complement but i cannot make this notion precise when the point is located on the vertical axis.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $(0,z)$ is on the vertical axis and $t = e^z$, $|\log(x) - z| > t/2$ when $0 < x < \ldots$